# typeahead.js manually select an option after it loads from remote

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I'm working on the location selector with typeahead 0.10.0 (https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js/tree/integration-0.10.0), so when my app loads I determine user's location and have city, state, country data availiable. My location search utilizing Google's Autocomplete.
What I want to do is to set the value of typeahed field with location string and after I get suggestions pick the first one (Usually it will be the only suggestion, since my location string is pretty accurate).

```
    geoip2.city(onSuccess, onError);

    var onSuccess = function(res) {
          if (res.city.names['en']) {

            var city = res.city.names['en'];
            var state = res.subdivisions[0]['iso_code'];
            var country = res.country['iso_code'];

            $('#city_selector.typeahead').typeahead('val', city + ', ' + state + ', ' + country).trigger({
              type: 'keypress',
              which: 13,
              keyCode: 13
            });
          }
        };

        var onError = function(err) {
          // body...
          console.log(err);
        };

        geoip2.city(onSuccess, onError);
```

I tried to use trigger, but it's not going to work because I need to wait for remote to return suggestions.

Comment: Try using the initialized event: https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js/tree/integration-0.10.0#custom-events

Comment: @Francis, thanks for reply! I'm not following you, could you explain more on how would you use 'initialized' event?

Comment: ever figure this one out?